# How to make use of "scp" command or any UNIX command in java , ie how to sfp a file from one Unix box to other in java

Tags: java

I need to write a code where , i need to sftp a tar file from one UNIX Box to other in java.
Im using "SSHFACTORY", i am able to execute all the commands but im not able to execute sftp command ... can any one please suggest

```
String hostname,username,password;
        System.out.println("Enter the machine to which you want to connect ");
        hostname = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter username : ");
        username = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter password : ");
        password = br.readLine();
        SshParameters sshParams = new SshParameters(hostname,username, password);
        SshSession session = new SshSession(sshParams);
        session.setShellPrompt("$");
        session.connect(10000);
        System.out.println("Login to websphe");
        session.send("sudo su - websphe");
        String contents = session.send("ls -ltr ");
                session.send("directory u want the file to copy");
                session.send("scp username@machineIp:"file u want to transfer" create.tar");
```

//Not able to execute this may at this point it is prompting for passwrd

can any one please suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider in your case creating a ssh key on the server1 and add it to server2 `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. In such way you will not be asked for password.

[Here](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html) is a tutorial for this.